# How can I load lua variables and functions without executing the script?

Tags: c, multithreading, lua

Everywhere I looked, I saw that the best practice for running lua scripts from many C threads is to have a different lua_State for each thread. Going from this point, be the following script:

```
local var1
local var2
-- etc.

function onClick(x, y)
-- Process mouse click
end

function onKey(k)
-- Process key stroke
end

-- Do some stuff
while(true) do
-- Do some stuff
end
```

where `onClick` and `onKey` are callback functions called by a Win32 application. These functions are called each one by one C thread. Each one of these have it's own lua_State. Therefore, there is a total of 3 C threads (and 3 lua_States): one for each of the above functions, and the last one for running everything that is not a function (while loop and stuff). So, since Lua can only sees what's in script after lua_dofile and lua_dofile executes everything there is, how can those functions be called without the whole script being executed? I just want one thread to be stuck in the infinite loop; the other ones must wait from the callback functions.

Comment: You can't. Move your `while` loop into a function, and have your C code call it.

Comment: Thanks, that worked fine. Now, how can I communicate betweet the threads, so that local variables altered by one could see by another?

Comment: You can't, at least not in Lua directly. `lua_state`s are completely separate from each other. You'll need a C API to do sharing, message passing, or whatever you need.

Comment: Any recommended API?

P.S: I don't get the purpose of `lua_newthread`. It's supposed to do that exactly what I need: share the same global variables of the main `lua_state` with the child states. Problem is its behavior is crazy.

Comment: `lua_newthread` creates new coroutines, not OS threads.

Comment: @Colonel, you can actually run code in lua_State* that returned by lua_newthread in different OS thread, but 1) it will be slow, because in most cases Lua code can't run in parallel and you'll get a lot of CPU context switches, 2) you **must insure** that you compile Lua with **mutex support**: there is defines for LOCK / UNLOCK operations in one of its C headers. AFAIK, Lua does not support this in default binary distribution.