# Load Lua file and use variables without executing functions

Tags: c++, lua

I am trying to load a table into C++ from Lua. This is how the file looks:

```
function alma(arg)
  print(arg)
end

sometable = {
  num = 5,
  text = "this is a string",

  nested = {
    {"a", alma("argument")},
    {"table", alma("arg")},
    {"element", alma("asd")}
  }
}
```

If I call `luaL_loadfile` I only get the chunk. If I call `lua_dofile` I get the elements, but the alma function runs for each element. In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40596253/how-can-i-load-lua-variables-and-functions-without-executing-the-script) SO thread, someone said to wrap these kinds of stuff into functions and call that to get the data. When i wrap/call the function the 3 alma functions run the moment i call the getter. How can i get `sometable` and its elements without executing the alma function?

Comment: You can use metatable on a table to implement lazy evaluation of some elements in that table.  So, `alma` will be invoked only when you access corresponding element for the first time.  This feature is transparent: you will not have to invoke some function explicitly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> and I'd like to have onClick events for gui elements, which would be
>   some functions, hence the {"some string", function} table elements

Ok, you need function called later. Just save value of that functiion, i.e. simply write its name:

```
nested = {
    {"a", func_argument},
    {"table", func_arg},
    {"element", func_asd}
  }
```

But you want to call same function, passing arguments. And you want that info saved as a function. So either define a function directly in the table, or call some function that will return another function, storing its args in a closure:

```
-- function to be called
function alma(arg)
    print(arg)
end

-- define functions in table
nested1 = {
    {"a", function() alma "argument" end},
    {"table", function() alma "arg" end},
    {"element", function() alma "asd" end}
}

-- or create function within another function
function alma_cb(name)
    return function() alma(name) end
end

nested2 = {
    {"a", alma_cb "argument"},
    {"table", alma_cb "arg"},
    {"element", alma_cb "asd"}
}
```

Comment: @val, the point is that a function is a value. It doesn't have a name but it might have one or variables or fields referring to it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't get any value without calling some function. Any chunk loaded is a function. Not the data, but function that will construct/return data. You must call it, so it will fill some global variables, or explicitly return values.
If you don't want `alma()` called, then don't call it. Fill your table without calling `alma()`.
 
For example:

```
return {
  num = 5,
  text = "this is a string",

  nested = {
    {"a", "argument"},
    {"table", "arg"},
    {"element", "asd"}
  }
}
```

You must load and call this chunk, it will construct and return table with `.nested` subtable, and `alma()` won't be called.

Comment: So i cannot have functions nested like that, and if I want to avoid automatic function calling at load time i have to avoid any reference to the function in data?

Comment: It feels like XY problem is involved. You're insisting on having functions, but don't want to call them. What's your exact task? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to write GUI data in lua, and load that into C++ so i dont have to keep recompiling the program, when i make slight adjustments, and I'd like to have onClick events for gui elements, which would be some functions, hence the {"some string", function} table elements.